# How to save .flv file from rtsp camera C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, libvlc

I'm trying to save streamed `rtsp` video from my IP camera using FFmpeg.exe command like this

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://[source_url_full_file_name] -acodec copy -vcodec copy [local_target_file_name].flv
```

but it is so hard to manage all process started for each camera so I decided to have an embedded managed thread that do the same thing

I've tried many libraries and codes but still no result.

any one have a code or links to achieve that using `C#`

Comment: It's not clear what's not working... Is the shown FFmpeg command not achieving the asked for _"How to save .flv file from rtsp camera"_??? Is your real question _"How to run FFmpeg as an external Process by C#?"_ where you can get a ProcessID etc involved? Research that option...

Comment: my question is not what the problem with this command, I've use it and worked very will , I've ProcessID it is easy but the management of these process is so hard , my question how do save flv from inside my application without calling any external application like ffmpeg.exe

Comment: So with your C# code you are currently able to receive camera data from RTSP server? Is the received media's **Payload** (after parsing RTP & UDP headers etc) in FLV format? If already FLV then just extract Payload bytes directly into a bytearray and append each incoming payload's bytes until end. Save the bytearray to disk as file (eg: `output.flv`)... If want to create FLV from scratch then look at [**FLV format Specs**](https://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf)

Comment: If RTSP is giving FLV data anyways then find it after IP/UDP/RTP headers. You should find bytes like `46 4C 56 01 05 00 00 00 09` this is an FLV header so you write these bytes and onwards bytes to disk or bytearray to store FLV bytes... If you have raw h264 frames then you'll have to make FLV container and package each h264 frame within own FLV tag (tag holds a/v data) so you'd (1) Make FLV header (2) Add Metadata tag (3) add A/V config tag (4) Make "video" type tags (11 byte header + h264 bytes + 4 byte footer)... Repeat step (4) for each h264 frame until you want video to end here..

Comment: I'll try to have RTSP as bytes and parsing it as you mention .. any one have links may explain more in details ??

Comment: I can only help you with making a valid FLV. But you need to show us what bytes your camera/server sends so we can advise. Is there anyway to show a small sample of received data (dump of **raw** bytes, no parsing)? Maybe get via using a tool like WireShark?

Comment: @VC.One start fram from wire shark `52:06:bd:40:8b:a4:60:1a:47:34:31:68:e5:ef:ce:9f:08:04:21:f8:5b:05:5c:8b:e0:68:47:8b:38:6d:73:a7:ff:ff:52:db:4e:8d:59:b5:a5:0b:fa:d3:b2:27:84:f0:02:83:a4:3c:fc:6b:be:63:40:17:65:86:c2:32:97:4e:a0:55:fa:d6:ef:fa:5d:24:b2:84:f2:10:d4:f3:6d:b6:d9:74:19:e5:ff:fd:1d:84:f0:09:ba:e6:e3:2d:83:77:72:cb:12:4c:b6:fd:f8:8f:95:43:e3:c2:01:c3:ee:0f:f2:48:af:81:56:6a:a7:97:64:70:f3:85:89:df:0d:1b:c3:b2:98:af:03:b0:06:39:da:19:04:fe:7b:f7:dd:cb:bf:2e:f1:f8:60:33:af:f4:92:fc:f8:42:25:72:e9:31:71:f8:5e:bf:ff:a2:bc:23:45:e8:4e:b8:ec:10:36:4f:9f:ff:c2:de:ff:e3:87:0a:f4:2f`

Comment: Those shown bytes do not contain any video codec or video container header (file beginning). I don't see any FLV or MP4 bytes. Also not enough bytes to hold a keyframe (image)... I'm curious what format does your camera actually send? No other C# tool can do this RTP connection for you? It's a big wheel to re-invent when things libraries like VLC and FFmpeg can already do it...